# Как проверить на null в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

AJAX возвращает объект json. В некоторых случаях json может быть null. Как лучше всего проверить объект на null? Правильно ли использовать такую проверку if(json)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Каноническое решение на jQuery:

```
if (jQuery.type( proveryamaya_peremennaya ) === "null") {
    console.log('eto null');
} else {
    console.log('eto ne null (sic!)');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает)

Comment: Вообще конечно ответ полушуточный был, ну ладно, раз подошел.

Answer (score 3):

Лучшая проверка на `null`

```
if (json === null) {}
```

не равно `null`

```
if (json !== null) {}
```

Comment: Так работает тоже) Спасибо.

Comment: Not enough jQuery

Answer (score 2):

```
if(obj.key == null) {
  console.log("Null");
} else {
  console.log(obj.key);
}
```

Comment: Нужно больше jQuery